# Wrong Hadoop DataNode - display in hadoop dfsadmin -report

Tags: hadoop

I am using - Multinode Hadoop configuration.

My Laptop - works as a Name Node -116.202.217.25

VMPayer Ubuntu image - Data Node. -172.16.197.128

**Name Node ->/etc/hosts entries are (I added 1st 2 lines)**

```
116.202.217.25     masterNode 
172.16.197.128     slaveNode

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Shankha-Bhattacharya-Toshiba

 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
   ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   fe00::0 ip6-localnet
   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
   ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**Data Node m/c /etc/hosts entries (I added slaveNode and masterNode entries)**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

172.16.197.128   slaveNode
116.202.217.25   masterNode

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Now I use masterNode and slaveNode in all configuration files in Name Node (Laptop) and VM (Data Node)

**Example - core-site.xml**

```
fs.default.name

hdfs://masterNode:54310
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
mapred.job.tracker

masterNode:54311
```

**Name Node JPS**

```
hadoop@Shankha-Bhattacharya-Toshiba:~/hadoop-1.0.3/bin$ jps
7844 NameNode
8135 SecondaryNameNode
15719 Jps
8287 JobTracke
```

Data Node JPS

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ jps
3148 TaskTracker
2933 DataNode
3804 Jps
```

**Open url - masternode:50070/dfshealth.jsp**

Then when I click **Browse the filesystem link** , I get following exception

```
Page redirected to -

masternode:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?namenodeInfoPort=50070&dir=/

Exception -

Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at masternode:50075.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.

If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

**How can I resolve this issue?**

**Another issue**

hadoop dfsadmin -report    - shows Data node is my NameNode(masterNode)
...where as I configured VM - as my Data Node ..

```
hadoop@Shankha-Bhattacharya-Toshiba:~/hadoop-1.0.3/bin$ ./hadoop dfsadmin -report
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Configured Capacity: 42176413696 (39.28 GB)
Present Capacity: 36319903744 (33.83 GB)
DFS Remaining: 36319870976 (33.83 GB)
DFS Used: 32768 (32 KB)
DFS Used%: 0%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Name: 116.202.217.25:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 42176413696 (39.28 GB)
DFS Used: 32768 (32 KB)
Non DFS Used: 5856509952 (5.45 GB)
DFS Remaining: 36319870976(33.83 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 86.11%
Last contact: Mon Jun 16 16:33:27 IST 2014
```

In NameNode(MasterNode) - in the masters file - I add   **masterNode** 
In the NameNode(MasterNode)  - in the slaves file I add  **slaveNode**

**Then why data node name shown Name: 116.202.217.25:50010, instead of 172.16.197.128 (slave/datanode ip)?**